# How do you make a code snippet?

Tags: support, code-formatting, stack-snippets

I know how to make an indented codeblock, but in many people's answers, I see a code snippet you can run. What is the syntax for making a snippet like this?

Comment: The [help] helps.

Comment: @Rizier123 I looked at the help center myself - but couldn't find anything to do with these kind of snippets - just the generic tab indentation for `<pre>` blocks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Click that button (highlighted orange) and you will be presented with what is essentially a jsFiddle-looking screen to input all your code blocks.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept in 7 minutes

Comment: 65,060 minutes now..... hello..... ?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I kinda forgot. ;)

Comment: Haha I was only joking. I honestly didn't think anyone would see this! Fair play though lol